# How to use DataSource in Struts action class? It gives a compilation error "Type mismatch"

Tags: java, jdbc, struts

I have defined the data source in `struts-config.xml`. I want to get a connection from it in a Struts action class.

The code is:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
    Connection con = null;
    DataSource ds;

    try {
        ds = getDataSource(request,"A");
        con = ds.getConnection();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

The line

```
        ds = getDataSource(request,"A");
```

gives the following compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataSource to DataSource
```

How can this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: It depends, what do you want to use the DataSource for?

Answer (score 1):

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataSource to DataSource

This compilation error just means that the type returned by `getDataSouce()` doesn't match the type as you declared the `ds` to be. This compilation error is also not really helpful since it doesn't include the package name. But it at least means that you're using two different `DataSource` classes from different packages.

You need to ensure that the type is [`javax.sql.DataSource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) everywhere.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq :)